# what is the shortcut used in vs code to display more info about a member function or variable

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am looking for the short cut key for visual studio that would list the class, library and other info about a command for example of something like word.len()

Comment: use the keybinding interface to search for a keybinding for a command

Comment: You may be referring to `Ctrl+Space`.